# Volume using triple integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A solid in the first octant is bounded by $y=x^2, y=0, z=0$ and $x+y+z=6$. I am tasked to use triple integration to compute its volume using order $dz \thinspace dx \thinspace dy$.

**My work.** Consider the solid to be of type $xy$ bounded below by the plane $z=0$ and bounded above by $z=6-x-y$. Its projection $R$ onto the $xy$-plane is given by the region bounded by $y=x^2$ and $x+y=6$. If it is to be classified of type II (using horizontal strips), then we would have to cut the region at $y=4$. Thus, setting up the integral, we  have
$$\int_0^4 \int_0^{\sqrt{y}} \int_0^{6-x-y} dz \ dx \ dy + \int_4^6 \int_0^{6-y} \int_0^{6-x-y} dz \ dx \ dy$$
which yields the answer $\frac{248}{15}$. Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: Please do not remove content after having gotten an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Please note the bound region is outside the parabolic cylinder* as one of the bounds is plane $y = 0$. See the diagram of the projection in xy-plane. What you are considering is the region shaded on the left. But what I think the question intends is the region on the right. It is the region bound by parabolic cylinder $y = x^2$ and planes $x+y+z = 0, y = 0, z = 0$.

[image]

For every point in the region in xy-plane, $0 \leq z \leq 6 - x - y$

Now for the region in xy-plane, if we integrate wrt. $x$ first, we need one integral.

$\sqrt y \leq x \leq 6 - y$

For bound of $y$, we see intersection of $x + y = 6$ and $y = x^2$

$x^2 + x - 6 = 0 \implies (x+3)(x-2) = 0$

As we are in first octant, $x= 2, y = 4$.

So integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \int_0^4 \int_{\sqrt y}^{6-y} \int_0^{6-x-y} dz \ dx \ dy = \cfrac{292}{15}$

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. However, isn't the bounded region supposed to be inside the cylinder? (my reference is the actual graph using Geogebra). While I am aware that integrating wrt $y$ is faster and easier, I'm supposed to use $dx \ dy$ here.

Comment: @Shanic Is the region inside the cylinder bound by the plane $y = 0$? Technically you can say that but more likely than not, given the plane $y = 0$ is one of the bounds, it should be the region outside of the cylinder. I have added a diagram. See if that clarifies.

Comment: Yep, I see it now. I might be overthinking it. How about if I'm tasked to integrate with respect to $x$ first, I can't seem to find the two surfaces with which the solid lies between.

Comment: @Shanic my answer is integrating $x$ before $y$. Are you saying $x$ first, even before $z$?

Comment: ok in that case, you should look at the projection in yz plane. Bounds of $x$ is $\sqrt y \leq x \leq 6 - y - z$, for bounds of $y$, lower bound is $y = 0$, for upper bound find intersection of $y = x^2$ and $x+y+z = 6$ which is $y + \sqrt y = 6 - z$. Finally $0 \leq z \leq 6$. So integral will be $\int_0^6 \int_0^{(-1/2 + \sqrt{25/4-z})^2} \int_{\sqrt y}^{6-y-z} \ dx \ dy \ dz$